# Works in Applescript but not in Shell

Tags: bash, applescript

I have written something in Applescript that I would like to change as a shell script.
The applescript is as follows:

```html
set computerlevel to do shell script "(profiles -P )" with administrator privileges
if computerlevel contains "F2CC78D2-A63F-45CB-AE7D-BF2221D41218" then
 set theAnswer to "Active Directory Bind Present"
else
 set theAnswer to "Active Directory Bind Not Present"
end if
```

It works fine but I would like to write shell script version. This is what I have come up with so far.

```html
#!/bin/sh
configprofiles='profiles -P'
if $configprofiles == "F2CC78D2-A63F-45CB-AE7D-BF2221D41218"; then
  echo "<result>Active Directory Bind Present.</result>"
 else
  echo "<result>Active Directory Bind Not Present.</result>"
 fi
```

I thought it was working but it was really coming up as a false positive. Instead of seeing if the entire string of F2CC78D2-A63F-45CB-AE7D-BF2221D41218 is present I believe it is merely looking for any of the characters resulting in the false positive. Does anyone know what is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple syntactical things... The most important thing is the addition of the `[...]` around your test. (You can also precede the comparison with `test`)

```
#!/bin/sh
if profiles -P  | grep attribute | awk '{print $4}' | grep -q "F2CC78D2-A63F-45CB-AE7D-BF2221D41218"
then
    echo "<result>Active Directory Bind Present.</result>"
else
    echo "<result>Active Directory Bind Not Present.</result>"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks @PeterSmith  Unfortunetly the result now is always negative or rather returning the result as "Active Directory Bind Not Present" when it actually is present. What I am trying to do is see if configuration profiles are installed on a Mac computer. The most accurate way I have found is to verify if the uuid of the profile exists in system profiler. The profiles -P command lists all that is contained in the system profile information. So I am trying to match that uuid with the actual name of the configuration profile, in this case "Apple Directory Bind"

Comment: @PeterSmith Perhaps there is away to put the applescript within a shell script since that is working? I just have no idea to echo the output in the same manner as the shell script.

Comment: I don't do apple anything (ick!) so I'm just correcting the syntax on your existing script. I'm assuming you've done the research re `profiles -P` and etc.

Comment: Oh, wait - are you saying `profiles -P` returns many lines? Then we need to use `grep -q` instead. Check edit about to be done.

Comment: By the way, who is this Peter Smith guy?

Comment: Sorry Peter, new here! I thought It showed your user name as  Peter Smith, but I see they were using that as an example. This command just lists the uuids: profiles="$(profiles -P | grep attribute | awk '{print $4}')"   That is what I am looking or matching against. Is that helpful?

Comment: No problem, Dondo Smith... :-)  See answer with edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

if profiles -P  | grep attribute | awk '{print $4}' | grep -q "F2CC78D2-A63F-45CB-AE7D-BF2221D41218"
then
    echo "<result>Active Directory Bind Present.</result>"
else
    echo "<result>Active Directory Bind Not Present.</result>"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks to Peter Bowers on this!

Answer (score 0):

Your script was almost complete but the comparison is exact. To create an "contains" comparison as in AppleScript you can wrap asterix around the string. Another thing I found is that the variable is holding a string and is not executing the code. To execute a command and set it's output to a variable you should use `$(command)`. Last but not least the other answers uses all extra commands and piping while a shell can handle this pretty well itself and doesn't need such a complex method. So your script would look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
configprofiles=$(profiles -P)
if [[ $configprofiles == *"F2CC78D2-A63F-45CB-AE7D-BF2221D41218"* ]]
then
    echo "<result>Active Directory Bind Present.</result>"
else
    echo "<result>Active Directory Bind Not Present.</result>"
fi
```